# VisualVM collect performance data over a period of time

Tags: visualvm

for Java I am using VisualVM to monitor CPU, Memory, Thread info. Is there a way from VisualVM to collect this information for a range of time so that i am able to present it in a graph.

In VisualVM under Monitor tab i am able to see CPU,Classes,Heap and thread graph. I would like to be able to collect this data over a period of time when i run my load test. Later on present it on graph for later analysis.

If VisualVM is not the tool please suggest alternate option.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Tracer plugin](http://java.dzone.com/visualvm-13) for monitoring. Select probes which suits your needs and you should be able to export monitored data, which can be used to construct the graph of your choice.

Comment: Thanks this helps is there a way to automate it in such a way that at a specific interval it records and stores it to a csv file.

Comment: No, there is no such automation.